# Check whether the following matrix is invertible. If so find the inverse matrix for it.

Tags: matrices

I had a preparation test for an exam, and I got this question. Check if the matrix is inversible, if yes find the inverse matrix.

So I checked if this matrice is invertible it with Laplace Method, but I had hard time finding the inverse matrix, there is so much calculation and the numbers end up in fractions. Are there any shortcuts/hacks to find inverse of such big matrix?

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be the matrix. You have
$$(A+I)^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
4&4&4&4\\
4&4&4&4\\
4&4&4&4\\
4&4&4&4
\end{pmatrix} = 4(A+I)$$

so
$$A^2+2A+I=4A+4I$$
i.e.
$$A \times \left(A-2I \right) = 3I, \quad \quad \quad \text{i.e.} \quad \quad \quad A \times \frac{1}{3}\left(A-2I \right) = I$$

So $A$ is invertible and
$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{3}(A-2I)= \frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -2 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -2 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This is a nice approach to the question. I have to ask however: why does $A\times(A-2I)=3I$ imply $A^{-1}$ exists? Of course if it *does* exist then $A^{-1}A\times(A-2I)=3A^{-1}\implies A^{-1}=(1/3)(A-2I)$, but its existence in the first place isn't immediately obvious to me

Comment: If you divide the equation $A \times \left(A-2I \right) = 3I$ by $3$, you get directly something like $A \times (...)=I$, which is the definition of being invertible. So this method is particularly effective because it gives the invertibility *and* the inverse of $A$ at the same time.

Comment: What is this method called? First time I see this, I thought I had to create an identity matrix and use Gauss Jordan Method?

Comment: @alkantra I don't think this method has a name. It just uses the fact having a polynomial $P$ such that $P(A)=0$ gives a lot of information about a matrice ! And using Gauss-Jordan is also a perfectly valid method, you can do it and check if you find the same result as me.